# System.DateTime formatting in F#

Tags: datetime, f#

I have the following f# code:

```
let mutable argNum = 0
let cmdArgs = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()

for arg in cmdArgs do
    printfn "arg %d : %s" argNum arg
    match argNum with
    | 1 -> pmID      <- System.Int32.Parse arg 
    | 2 -> startDate <- System.DateTime.Parse arg
    | 3 -> endDate   <- System.DateTime.Parse arg
    | _ -> ()
    argNum <- argNum + 1
```

for the date parameters, the argument comes in the form: "1-1-2011", so "M-D-YYYY"
when i write the dates into the xml serializer, I get the following format:

```
1/1/2011 12:00:00 AM
```

I'd like to remove the Time piece completely. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this one?

```
(DateTime.Parse arg).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
```

Comment: very very close. i'm now getting this: "02-01-2011" how do I remove the quotes??

Answer (score 3):

By default  `DateTime` instances are serialized using the "dateTime" [datatype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.datatype.aspx) for serialization. You can change it by annotating your type to use "date" instead, which will serialize it in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` - if this doesn't work for you just serialize a string instead that holds the format of your choice.

You can set the custom serialization attribute like this:

full datetime:        `[<XmlAttribute("start-date", DataType = "dateTime")>]`

just the date part:    `[<XmlAttribute("start-date", DataType = "date")>]`

Example:

```
[<Serializable>]
type DateTest() = 
  let mutable startDate = DateTime.Now
  [<XmlAttribute("start-date", DataType = "date")>]
  member x.StartDate with get() = startDate and set v = startDate <- v
```

Comment: problem is, i'm not serializing an attribute "start-date". I"m serializing a parameter element that, in this instance, has a start-date attribute, though it might not in other instances.